# How to CSS select each first div without class after div with class?

Tags: html, css

How to CSS select each first div without class following after div with certain class? Example:

```
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div></div> <!-- must be selected -->
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div></div> <!-- must be selected -->
<div></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div></div> <!-- must be selected -->
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div></div> <!-- must be selected -->
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
```

Is it possible to select it without JS/JQuery?

Comment: You are trying to select all the elements without `someclass` class or just the next to the `someclass` element?

Comment: @Mr_Green First nonclass sibling element next to the "someclass" element

Comment: This is exactly how I interpreted your requirements. Check my answer below.

Comment: Remember to click the checkmark left of the answer that best helped you solve the described problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try https://jsfiddle.net/jr9wsr49/

**CSS**

```
.someclass + div:not(.someclass) {
  background:green
}
```

Comment: It should be `.someclass` but not `.some-class`.

Comment: Please change .some-class to .someclass to not confuse those who will need it in the future and I will mark it as the first correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Kainax: Updated my answer. its my bad typo. thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

you can try using following CSS

```
   .someclass + div:not(.someclass, .someclass) {
    }
```

Use can pass multiple values in not selector if you have different classes in this structure

Comment: Good ans, I was not aware of passing multiple selectors... thanks for providing the info.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

You can simply do in `:not()`

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/

```css
div{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:yellow;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.someclass + div:not(.someclass) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div></div>
<!-- must be selected -->
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div></div>
<!-- must be selected -->
<div></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div></div>
<!-- must be selected -->
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div></div>
<!-- must be selected -->
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
```

Comment: this will select all the div's which do not have .someclass, not the first one

Comment: @NileshMahajan use ` + ` method is css. like this .someclass + div{ ... }

Comment: @NileshMahajan Hope you could understand with the updated answer

Comment: you changed your answer to exactly match my answer.. what should I understand from your answer?

Comment: @NileshMahajan I have answered to **Kainax** and let him gain knowledge. There is nothing for you to understand from my answer because already know that :)

Answer (score 1):

A good option here is also to use another class.

The reason is that by defining a css selector that is tightly tied to your HTML structure you create brittle code that may break easily in future.

For example, you load your HTML into a CMS that formats by adding `<br />`'s and `<p>`'s (like Wordpress) and immediately your css breaks, quite possibly in the hands of a not particularly technical person. Or, you (or a colleague) come back to your code in a few weeks or months with a legitimate reason to interrupt the gap with a new html element. Again the code breaks and rather than just writing new stuff you have to fix old stuff and write new stuff.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1e2p1df/3/) adds `<p class="some-unexpected-future-situation"></p>` to demonstrate how the css is brittle

By using another class you also convey clearer meaning in your HTML and CSS. Currently in the HTML there's nothing to say the `<div>` targeted is special and the css declaration doesn't directly relate to the element it effects. This is a small thing

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1e2p1df/4/) involves a class - see how it works even with the unexpected change and also how the HTML and the CSS are somewhat clearer?

Another thing too is that using another class has massive browser support, larger than `:not` which is not supported on IEs less than 9.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood the OP, he wants to target only each first vanilla `<div>` following directly after `<div class="someclass">`, and that they specifically want to target this `<div>` only if it has ***no class***, rather than not having `.someclass`.

This can be achieved using a combination of `:not`, the *attribute selector* and the *adjacent sibling selector* `+`:

```
.someclass + div:not[class] {
    /* put your styles here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with CSS. Check the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector:

```
.someclass + :not(.someclass){
     /* style here */
}
```

Comment: this will select all siblings, not the first adjacent one

Comment: @downvoter check the update and remove the downvote.

Comment: This would select **all** sibling elements lacking `.someclass`, not only the *one* that directly follows a `.someclass`.

Comment: @connexo refresh your page.. I updated long back. :)

Answer (score 0):

use the :not() selector...

```css
div.someclass+div:not(.someclass) {color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="someclass">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="someclass">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="someclass">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
<!-- must be selected -->
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="someclass">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="someclass">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="someclass">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
<!-- must be selected -->
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="someclass">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="someclass">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="someclass">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="someclass">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
<!-- must be selected -->
<div class="someclass">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="someclass">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
<!-- must be selected -->
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<div class="someclass"></div>
```